# Show f(z)/z is bounded

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

if $\lim\limits_{|z| \to \infty} \frac{f(z)}{z} = 0$ then how do I show that f is bounded. Intuitively, this makes sense to me but I having trouble writing it out formally. I was thing for $|z|>N$, $|f(z)/z|<\epsilon$ and then we know |1/z| will be less than some $\epsilon^2$. Then can I say that these two facts give us that $|f(z)|<$ some number? Does that even help me?

Answer (score 2):

Since $f(1/z)$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$ with $\lim_{z\to 0} zf(1/z) = \lim_{|z| \to \infty} f(z)/z = 0$, $f(1/z)$ has a removable singularity at $z = 0$. So $f(1/z)$ is bounded in a deleted neighborhood of $0$, which implies $f(z)$ is bounded away from $0$, i.e., there exists $R, M > 0$ such that $|f(z)| \le M$ for all $|z| \ge R$. Since $f$ is continuous on the closed disk $|z| \le R$, it bounded by some number $M'$ on that disk. Thus, $f$ is bounded by $\max\{M,M'\}$.

Comment: "So f(1/z) is bounded in a deleted neighborhood of 0, which implies f(z) is bounded away from 0. " How does this statement make sense? Could you explain this further?

Comment: @user153009 there exists $R > 0$ and $M > 0$ such that $|f(1/z)| \le M$ for all $z$ such that $0 < |z| \le R$. So for $|z| \ge R$, $0 < \frac{1}{|z|} \le \delta$, which implies $|f(1/(1/z))| \le M$, i.e., $|f(z)| \le M$.

Comment: |z|>=R => 1/R >= 1/|z| ?

Comment: @user153009 no, but it was supposed to be "So for $|z| \ge \frac{1}{R}$, $0 < \left|\frac{1}{z}\right| \le {R}$, which impies $|f(1/(1/z))| \le M$, i.e., $|f(z)| \le M$".

Comment: But to show its bounded on the complex plane, don't we need to show its bounded when |z|<R and |z|>R. If we use 1/R, it may not cover some areas.

Comment: @user153009 you're misunderstanding. I used $1/R$ in these comments, but if you're trying to relate this $R$ to the problem, then all you have to do change the $R$ to $1/R$ in my comments. Now, I already said in my answer that $f$ is bounded by $M$ for $|z| \ge R$ and $f$ is bounded by some $M'$ for $|z| \le R$ (by continuity of $f$ on the closed disk $|z| \le R$), hence $f$ is bounded in $\Bbb C$ by $\max\{M,M'\}$.

Comment: Okay, I do that so you're statement becomes for |z|>R,0<|1/z|<1/R which may not imply that f(z) is bounded outside R because |1/z| must be less than R for me to use the first fact you provided.

Comment: @user153009 no, you're still missing it. For $|z| \ge R$, $0 < |\frac{1}{z}| \le \frac{1}{R}$, which implies $|f(z)| \le M$. Thus $|f(z)|$ is bounded by $M$ for $|z| \ge R$.

Answer (score 1):

Another edited:

Let $a_0 = f(0)$ , and let $g(z)=\frac{f(z)-a_0}{z}$. $g(z)$ is entire, we also have that $g$ is bounded (since the limit is finite). So from Liuoville we have that $g$ is constant.So $g$ must the constant ero function , so $f(z)=f(0)$ .

After the question was edited:

Since it is entire we can write $f$ as a taylor series, since the limit goes to 0 you will be left with only $f(z) = a_0$ , i.e. f is constant (Elseway choose the biggest $m$ such that $a_m\neq 0$, where $a_m$ is the coeffiecent of $x^m$ in the taylor series of $f$ . Then we get that $\lim \limits_{|z| \to \infty} \frac{f(z)}{z} = \lim \limits_{|z| \to \infty}a_m z^{m-1} \neq 0 $. Contradiction)

Before the question was edited:

Take $f(z) =z^2$ and your argument fails...

You can prove your function is bounded in small enough environment:

If $f(z)/z$ goes to 0 as $|z|$ goes to zero, then for small enough $r>0$ we have that for every $z \in B_r(0) \ \ \ |f(z)/z| \leq 1$.

Meaning that $|f| \leq |z| <1$ in small enough environment , meaning $f$ is bounded in small enough environment of $0$.

Comment: if we take |(z^2)/z|=|z| then this doesn't satisfy the assumption that this limit needs to go to 0. It would go to infinity in this case. Sorry I made an error in the question, I will edit it.

Comment: Is $f(z)$ holomorphic

Comment: Yes it is entire

Comment: @user153009 I edited the solution

Comment: but its not actually constant. It's only constant as |z|->infinity ? how would that imply boundedness?

Comment: @user153009 Again, assume toward a contradiction (like I said in the brackets) , that it is not cosntant, then the taylor series contains some non-trivial coeffiecent $a_m$ for some $x_m$ (m>0), but then if we then divide by $z$ we get that the limit won't be zero (it will be equal to $a_1$ if the function is linear , elseways the limit is  infinity)

Comment: So you get that the only coeffiecent of the taylor expansion that can be non-zero is the coeffiecent of $z^0$, if he is zero than it is also okay, anyway you get constant function

Comment: Okay, I have written out the taylor series and I see how all of the terms of f(z)/z that degree>=1 require that all the associated coefficients go to 0 but what if some terms are positive and some are negative

Comment: It doesn't matter, as $z \to \infty$ the value of the limits depends only on the leading coefficent (all the other terms become really small compared to the leading coeffiicent)

Think about this it is elementary.If you agree with my answer you can accept it by clicking on the "check" sign

Comment: @user153009 does it mean you understood the solution?

Comment: I understand how the solution works except I don't really understand how I can say terms vanishing => coefficients are 0. If there is some kind of article or something you could refer me to, that would be really awesome.

Comment: Better idea: g(z) = (f(z)-a_0)/z . Using liouville you get that g(z) is constant , moreover it is the zero constant functin. i.e. f is constant.
I think now my explanation is more clear (my previous explanation is not clear enough, you are right)

Comment: @user153009 I understood your problem with my solution, how about the new one?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(z)=\dfrac{f(z)}{z}$

Let $\epsilon>o$ then as $|g(z)\rightarrow 0$ as $z\rightarrow \infty$ by definition we will get some $G>0$(large) such that $|g(z)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|z|>G$

Similarly as $|g(z)|\rightarrow 0 $ as $z\rightarrow -\infty$ then we can find a $G_1$ such that as $|z|<-G;|g(z)|<\epsilon $

Choose $M$such that both conditions hold (which is possible)

Then we are only left with the compact set $B[0,\dfrac{M}{2}]$ and since $g$ is entire and hence uniformly continuous on a compact set and hence bounded and thus so is $f$

Comment: I dont think this works because infinity in complex can be any direction. Here you are assuming infinity and negative infinity.

Comment: I have used modulus check that