# If $f$ is entire and $\lim_{|z|\to\infty} \frac{|f(z)|}{|z|}=0$, how can I show $f(z)=f(0)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function and $\lim_{|z|\to\infty} \frac{|f(z)|}{|z|}=0$. I want to show $f(z)=f(0)$ for all $z$.

I'm guessing Liouville's theorem might help, but I don't know how.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3050625/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1176705/42969

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply Liouville's theorem to the bounded entire function $g(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(0)}z$ if $z\ne0,$ $g(0)=f'(0).$

Comment: @JohnSmith Since this was a duplicate, I have to delete my answer (I just got a downvote on it, probably to warn me). For this I need you to unaccept it.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nz^n$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, then
$$ a_n=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{D(0,R)}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi R^n}\int_0^{2\pi}f(Re^{i\vartheta})e^{-iN\vartheta}d\vartheta $$
for all $R>0$. Now,
$$ |a_n|\leqslant\frac{1}{2\pi R^n}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(Re^{i\vartheta})|e^{-iN\vartheta}d\vartheta $$
and for $n\geqslant 1$, we have $\lim\limits_{R\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{|f(Re^{i\vartheta})|}{R^n}=0$ from which we conlude that $a_n=0$ for $n\geqslant 1$ by the dominated convergence theorem and therefore $f(z)=a_0=f(0)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Bonjour, comme c'était un doublon, nous "devons" détruire nos réponses.